# ngen.exe full memory usage and system lockup

Tags: c#, .net

If I ever leave my computer idle for more than 20 minutes, it locks up. This also happens whenever I compile and run a program in c# visual studio 2010. At first I had no idea at all what the issue was, but after a bit of debugging, I found it was ngen.exe using 100% of my computer's 8GB of ram. Using resource monitor I just managed to suspend the process and work out what "ngen.exe" is.

It turns out it is the .net native image generator. I tried once leaving my pc on for about 5 hours, but it didn't clear up. I'm guessing a memory leak somewhere. Any ideas?

Note, I am running windows 8.1, 3.5GHz amd fx 8320 cpu, and 8gb of ram.

Comment: Try generating dumps (can be done by rightclicking in Task Manager) and analyze them in Visual Studio or windbg.

Comment: Any possibility that your machine is downloading Windows Updates to the .NET framework? I believe during the install process it performs an NGen operation on the updated .NET libraries to compile them down to the machine level.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem for a while.  Whenever I open Visual Studio, "Microsoft Common Language Runtime native compiler" process will start consuming about 4 GB of RAM and 15% of the CPU.

I tried killing the task, deleting registry entries, disabling the tasks in the task scheduler, but nothing worked.  The process would still run when I open Visual Studio.

Finally, I found the solution by renaming ngen.exe which lives in the Windows folder that even local admin cannot easily rename.

**Note**: This should be your last option.

To rename ngen.exe, run PowerShell or Command Prompt as admin in the directory where the ngen.exe is located and execute these commands:

```
takeown /f ngen.exe 

icacls ngen.exe /grant Username:F
```

These commands will assign ownership to the specified username, and then you can rename `ngen.exe`.

Comment: Killing ngen and making it unavailable is hardly an answer to anything, that is entirely the wrong thing to do. Instead, OP should've looked into why ngen was running in the first place. However, this is a five year old question, they did some big optimizations way back and this problem may not even exist any more.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I agree this is not the perfect solution. I just wanted to share my experience so others can benefit if they like to prevent ngen.exe from running. I tried many different solutions put forth on various sites, but none worked for me. As the last resolution, I had to rename the ngen.exe. FYI, I encountered this issue recently (so not an old problem). This was my first attempt to help other developers by joining Stack Overflow. It's sad that you down-voted my answer, but you certainly have the right to do so. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fairly clear that when it keeps happening on idle and never stops, ngen is stuck doing something it shouldn't.
(I've found other posts that say about letting it finish or helping it to finish by running.. was it ngentask or something?... but none of those worked.)
I'm suspicious it's related to updates that Windows is failing to install, but never mind.

I'm finding this post for a second time but what I was really looking for was the post at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-stopuninstall-ngenexe/615fb76e-3340-453b-958d-c0a1c420d806
where Steven has the solution/work-around that I recall worked for me last time:

> ... navigated through Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > .NET Framework and lo! the offending tasks were revealed in 32 and 64 bit versions, triggering on Idle. Right click to disable.
>
> The grim implication is that this will need to be done again whenever .NET Framework moves to a new version.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to disable it. I was, however, able to reschedule it to fit my timetable. To do that, I had to click on the <kbd>Properties</kbd> of the tasks with triggers listed.

Then, I had to change the "User or Group" to some form of Admin. (Entering as an Admin didn't work for me; I'm beginning to think my problems may be unique to me?)

1. Unclick *Run with highest privilege*
2. Click on the *Triggers* tab

Here you can change when the program operates. The directions are pretty simple. If you mess up (I tried to reschedule something, putting the Action in a queue and got a MESSAGE! So I went back and put that Action into a regular schedule. Problem solved.) I'm sure your computer will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution of this, which works.

we are going to delete this folder v4.0122 may be your version different
and install the new .net_framework

just follow the steps carefully

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64
open this directory

then open the cmd as administrator and cd to above path

then type these three commands

1. **takeown /f v4.0122 /r /d y**
2. **icacls v4.0122 /grant administrators:F /t**
3. **rmdir /s /q v4.0122**

folder is delete if not (then stop the ngen.exe process in task manager) and  repeat the 3rd command

now do the same steps for
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET**Framework**

after both the folders delete now restart your pc

after restart the error may appear .net framework 4.0 need to run these application (ignore it)

now install the latest dotnet framework and copy the path of installation folder and add in the
Enviroment variables -> system variables->path

like my path is C:\Program Files\dotnet\

after this, restart your pc
optional:the windows also get update of .net 3.5 or 4.0 framework.
then update it as well